# Why doesn't form nested in p validate as XHTML

Tags: xhtml, forms

Take for instance this XHTML snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>A webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <form action="something.php" method="get">
      <input type="submit" value="Hello"/>
    </form>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The tree should be valid, however this won't parse correctly in a browser.

Comment: doesn't the validation page make some suggestions?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Look at the error messages that you get when you try that with http://validator.w3.org

Apart from a warning that you haven't specified a character encoding (and that it's therefore assuming UTF-8), the main error is that a `<p>` isn't allowed to contain non-inline content. You can either remove the `<p>` and `</p>` completely, or, move them inside the `<form>`.

As for 'why', it's because that's how it's defined in the schema which defines what is and what is not valid XHTML. If you look at [this section of the XHTML definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html#s_textmodule) you'll see that `<p>` is only allowed to contain text or 'inline' (not 'block') tags. However a [`<form>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html#s_extformsmodule) counts as 'block' content not as 'inline' content.

In other words, a form can contain paragraphs, but a paragraph cannot contain forms.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer (so far) to actually explain what the problem is

Comment: +1 for the same reason here too. Everyone else is just like "yeah, it doesn't validate according to validator.w3c.org

Comment: Content-Type should be determined only by HTTP header.

Comment: Still nonsense for me. Form is not a block content neither is an inline content, it is a virtual element just to the purpose of specifying submit action etc.. It's nonsense that I can't have two forms (for example one with method GET and the other POST) in the same paragraph.

Comment: @Teejay Normally a form contains or surrounds several elements, e.g. the submit button and all the input elements. The several input elements are often in separate paragraphs or list items.

Comment: @ChrisW OR, you may want to have two elements (belonging to different forms) in the same paragraph. That's exactly why I came here.

Comment: @Teejay Another reason might be that a form can contain a block; therefore it can't be contained within a paragraph, because a paragraph is defined as only being able to contain inline content. Anyway you might do what you want e.g. by doing something like, changing a CSS `display` to use `inline-block`, and/or by using a `<div>` instead of a `<p>

Comment: @ChrisW Yeah, I know, but still think that's a nonsense. I mean, if form can contain a block but p doesn't, that situation might be illegal, not the form inside a p.

Comment: @Teejay I don't know but maybe t's still true [in html5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html) -- i.e. `<p>` and `<form>` are both "flow content" but `<p>` can contain [only "phrasing content"](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#phrasing-content).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://validator.w3.org/), because:

> Line 8, Column 44: document type does
>   not allow element "form" here; missing
>   one of "object", "ins", "del", "map"
>   start-tag    ✉
>   The mentioned element is not allowed
>   to appear in the context in which
>   you've placed it; the other mentioned
>   elements are the only ones that are
>   both allowed there and can contain the
>   element mentioned. This might mean
>   that you need a containing element, or
>   possibly that you've forgotten to
>   close a previous element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is
>   that you have attempted to put a
>   block-level element (such as "p" or
>   "table") inside an inline element
>   (such as "a", "span", or
>   "font").
>
> Line 9, Column 40: document type does
>   not allow element "input" here;
>   missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3",
>   "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre",
>   "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del"
>   start-tag
>       input type="submit" value="Hello"  The mentioned
>   element is not allowed to appear in
>   the context in which you've placed it;
>   the other mentioned elements are the
>   only ones that are both allowed there
>   and can contain the element mentioned.
>   This might mean that you need a
>   containing element, or possibly that
>   you've forgotten to close a previous
>   element.
>
> One possible cause for this message is
>   that you have attempted to put a
>   block-level element (such as "p" or
>   "table") inside an inline element
>   (such as "a", "span", or
>   "font").

Comment: +1 for the following: "... you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "p" or "table") inside an inline element (such as "a", "span", or "font")."

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), which will tell your what is invalid with most (X)HTML and CSS documents.

Comment: I think he probably realizes this since he already knows it isn't validating. He was asking why it was invalid, not whether.

Comment: Well seeing as the W3C validator explains pretty well why it's invalid, I figured that was the most informative way to solve the problem. It's better to tell someone how to solve a problem, rather than just give them the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can't put form inside paragraph. Write like this:

```
<body>
  <form action="something.php" method="get">
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Hello"/>
  </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: He asked _WHY_ it doesn't validate, not how to fix it.

Answer (score -3):

I ran a test with your HTML code through [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/check) and the result is that you need to swap the P and FORM tags for it to pass as valid W3C HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <title>A webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="something.php" method="get">
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Hello"/>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He asked _WHY_ it doesn't validate, not how to fix it.