# Different browser behavior regarding jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, css-selectors

Consider the following HTML5 code in body:

```
<p id="p1">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
<p id="p2">
    <form action="/index.php">
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</p>
```

And the following javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("$(#p1 input).length: " + $("#p1 input").length + "\n$(#p2 input).length: " + $("#p2 input").length);
});​
```

Here are different browsers' outputs:

**Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421**

```
$(#p1 input).length: 3
$(#p2 input).length: 3
```

**Chromium Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 (144678)**

```
$(#p1 input).length: 3
$(#p2 input).length: 0
```

**Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 17.0.1**

```
$(#p1 input).length: 3
$(#p2 input).length: 0
```

Can anyone please explain why?

http://jsfiddle.net/LKStL/2/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022041/why-doesnt-form-nested-in-p-validate-as-xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

Block elements like `form` aren't allowed inside `p` elements. It's invalid HTML, hence jQuery breaks trying to parse it. I can only speculate that maybe it works in Internet Explorer because Explorer doesn't follow HTML rendering standards (ie: it should break but doesn't).

**Solution:** Put your `form` tag outside of the `p` or change `p` to an element that allows block elements, like a `div`.