# How to return php code into html body

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I am building a simple form script that collects a users email and returns a PIN.

The input sits in standard HTML below:

```
<p>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="srEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="srEmail" class="form-control input-lg" id="srEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="srSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Generate PIN</button>
    </form>
</p>
```

I have the following `if` statement that checks the database to see if the email already exists, and if the user would like a PIN reminder.

```
if($num_rows != 0) {//if email found in table
    ?>
    Email already registered, would you like a PIN reminder?
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="srSend" value="Click here to get pin reminder" />
    <input type="hidden" name="srEmail" value="<?php echo strtolower($email);?>" />
    </form>
    <?php
    exit;
}
```

At the moment, this returns the result to the user as a new page; how do I put this in the actual HTML of the body page, so it would actually appear below the original form input in a new `<p>` element?

Comment: You want to do this without refreshing the page?

Comment: Use ajax to get without refresh

Comment: You have to use AJAX to modify the page without refreshing. Showing how to rewrite a page in this way is more than we can do in a simple Q/A format.

Comment: More than a Q/A can reasonably support, but fortunately Wikipedia (and the internet at large) has us covered: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)#Example

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of cake with jquery.post

include the jquery library in your html head and you'll need a short script to get the php content by ajax

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#yourForm').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var data=$('#yourForm').serialize();
       $.post('yourphp.php',data,function(html){
          $(body).append(html);
       });
    });
});
</script>
</head>    
<body>
<p>
        <form id="yourForm" class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="srEmail">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="srEmail" class="form-control input-lg" id="srEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" name="srSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Generate PIN</button>
        </form>
    </p>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks, in your script, where would I put the HTML I want returned after the form submission? in yourphp.php?

Comment: @alias51 yes that's right, I didn't test it but if you get any errors let me know

Comment: For the record: `<p>` tags can exist inside a `<form>` tag, but not vice versa (according to the XHTML specification). Also see [Why doesn't form nested in p validate as XHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022041/why-doesnt-form-nested-in-p-validate-as-xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

You could able to achieve that without [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) too. Simply use a hidden `iframe` in your main page, then set the target attribute of your `form` to the `iframe` as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php" target="myIframe">
.....
</form>
<p id="theResultP"></p>

<iframe src="#" name="myIframe" style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

The question now, How could you make the page loaded in the iframe "page.php" to interact with the opener page to update the `p`. This may be done as follow:

```
//page.php
<script>
result = parent.document.getElementById('theResultP');
result.innerHtml = "<b>The message you want</b>"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I get what you asking for,but this is my solution :

```
<p>
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="srEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="srEmail" class="form-control input-lg" id="srEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="srSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Generate PIN</button>
    </form>
</p>

    <?php
    if (isset($message)){
    <p><?php print $message ?></p>
    ?>

<?php
    }
?>
```

and in top of your file write something like this :

```
<?php 
if($_post['srSend']){
$message='write your message here';
}
```

?>