# Symfony2 using {{ form() }} is closing <p>

Tags: php, symfony

I can't find any info why is that happening. I've got a really simple form, containing hidden field and submit button. I'd like to render it next to other button in paragraph like that:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('tfpt_badania_institution_edit', { 'id' : institution.id }) }}">Edytuj</a>
  {{ form(deleteForm) }}
</p>
```

When i check output html code Firefox shows:

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/BadaniaLekarskie/web/app_dev.php/institution/edit/1">Edytuj</a>
 <form method="post" action="/BadaniaLekarskie/web/app_dev.php/institution/delete">
<div id="form"><input type="hidden" id="form_id" name="form[id]" value="1" /><div><button type="submit" id="form_send" name="form[send]"    class="btn btn-primary">Usuń</button></div><input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="23b8c1c31bca9b396233dff5c0f85a9280c5afe1" /></div>
  </form>
</p>
```

But when i go into html structure i got sth like this:

[image: DOM structure problem]

And now - form button goes under the first one. Anyone can explain me why is that happening and how can i prevent it?

Comment: What if you put `Hi there` string between `form` and `</p>`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gedLJtk.jpg

Comment: What if you remove `{{ form }}` tag entirely then? I don't believe it happens. It looks like you've messed up with `<p>` tags somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest non-inline tags inside a `<p>`. The third image you're linking isn't the "html structure", it's a view of the DOM. The browser sees this invalid markup and corrects it by closing the `<p>` tag. The other unopen `<p>` is also given an open tag, with nothing in it.

As for why that isn't valid, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022050/343911)