# Why is a <div> tag or <form> tag written as a child to a <p> tag in an HTML code rendered by Chrome as not a child, but a sibling of the <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, paragraph

**My markup (form tag can be replaced with div tag):**

```
<p data-id="0">
  Please click a button
  <form class="box">
    <button data-target="choco" onclick="drink(event, this)">CHOCO</button>
    <button data-target="milk" onclick="drink(event, this)">MILK</button>
  </form>
</p>
```

**What Chrome renders, when I inspect it:**

```
<p data-id="0">
  Please click a button
</p>
<form class="box">
  <button data-target="choco" onclick="drink(event, this)">CHOCO</button>
  <button data-target="milk" onclick="drink(event, this)">MILK</button>
</form>
<p></p>
```

**...but when I use Javascript to fix this, it works:**

```
let p = document.querySelector('p[data-id]');
p.children;
//evaluates to:  HTMLCollection []
p.nextElementSibling;
//evaluates to: <form class=​"infobox">​…​</form>​
let a = p.nextElementSibling;
p.appendChild(a);
p.children;
//evaluates to: HTMLCollection [form.infobox]
```

**Chrome now renders:**

```
<p data-id="0">
  Please click a button
  <form class="box">
    <button data-target="choco" onclick="drink(event, this)">CHOCO</button>
    <button data-target="milk" onclick="drink(event, this)">MILK</button>
  </form>
</p>
<p></p>
```

I don't get the same issues when I replace the p *tag* with a div *tag*:

```
<div data-id="0">
  Please click a button
  <form class="box">
    <button data-target="choco" onclick="drink(event, this)">CHOCO</button>
    <button data-target="milk" onclick="drink(event, this)">MILK</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Chrome renders the above properly:**

```
<div data-id="0">
  Please click a button
  <form class="box">
    <button data-target="choco" onclick="drink(event, this)">CHOCO</button>
    <button data-target="milk" onclick="drink(event, this)">MILK</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Please what is going on here?
I use Chrome "Version 84.0.4147.89"
I haven't tested this on other browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022041/why-doesnt-form-nested-in-p-validate-as-xhtml/1022050#:~:text=You%20can%20either%20remove%20the,them%20inside%20the%20.&text=However%20a%20counts%20as,a%20paragraph%20cannot%20contain%20forms.

Comment: You cant nest block-level elements inside inline-elements

Comment: With js it works, why? See my example code.

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation bypasses HTML parsing rules allowing you to construct invalid  structures.

Comment: @Quentin OK Tnx